# Lengthening a song when producing a slide show on my new MacBook Air

Tags: editing, audio

I'm producing a slide show on my new MacBook Air but my song is too short.  Is there a way to lengthen my 2-minute song to maybe 3+ minutes without making it sound edited?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably time stretch it a bit without anyone noticing, but trying to stretch the length by 50% would be too much for any algorithm.

You best bet would be to edit in one of the verses or choruses twice. If the song has sufficient similarity at your cut points you can make this totally seamless. If the cuts don't match perfectly, you can add a little cross-fade to smooth it out. This is pretty easy in any modern audio editor.